# XMLHttpRequest returns console error

Tags: javascript, java, xmlhttprequest, httprequest

I'm trying to get an array from the java backend to the javascript frontend. When I try to get that array I get an error that states: "localhost:4242/decks: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.localhost:4242/decks: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https."

```
function httpGetAsync(theUrl, callback) {
let xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200)
        callback(xmlHttp.responseText);
};
xmlHttp.open("GET", theUrl, true);
xmlHttp.send(null);
}

function getDeck() {
httpGetAsync('localhost:4242/decks', function (response) {
    response.forEach(function (deckName) {
        console.log(deckName);
    });
});
}
```

Someone who is willing to help me?

Comment: Open the file through xampp or any other webserver, not directly in your browser.

Comment: I launch the project from Intellij Idea and have wampp running for the database